# Did the MCMC model converge?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, traceplots

Would you consider model with these MCMC traceplots and R-hat values as converged, and good enough for publication in a peer-reviewed journal? My peers claim convergence is good; the models ran for two weeks already. But by my opinion, the models need much more iterations and thinning and are not acceptable for publication in a peer-reviewed journal as they are.

[image]

Comment: Hi, personally I think at least some parameters seem suspicious, based on these traceplots and Rhat statistics. Especially the fourth plot on row one (with Rhat = 2.75) seems to show poor mixing. If I remember correctly, the Stan team indicates that any Rhat values above 1.01 could potentially be problematic. That being said, if your sampling already ran for two weeks, then maybe the model needs to be re-parametrized or otherwise changed. I don't know if running for any longer would give any additional benefit.

Comment: @MauritsM You could turn that into an answer

Comment: Thanks, Frans, I will.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think at least some parameters seem suspicious, based on these traceplots and Rhat statistics. Especially the fourth plot on row one (with Rhat = 2.75) seems to show poor mixing. If I remember correctly, the Stan team indicates that any Rhat values above 1.01 could potentially be problematic. See, for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08008

That being said, if your sampling already ran for two weeks, then maybe the model needs to be re-parametrized or otherwise changed. I don't know whether running your sampler any longer would give you better sampling diagnostics.